# I need to check if neighboring positions on a board are "paths"

Tags: python, if-statement

The function I'm working in relies on the function `mazesol.getBlock(board, x, y)`. I need to check all of the neighboring positions (up, down, left, right) on the board. Would I write it like this?

```
if mazesol.getBlock(board, ((x+1),(x-1)),((y+1),(y-1))) == 'path':
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to check each adjacent tile from your current x, y position.  Why don't you enumerate all of those possibilities first so its more readable for you :

```
//pseudo code...
up =mazesol.getBlock(board, x, y + 1);
down = mazesol.getBlock(x, y - 1);
left = mazesol.getBlock(x - 1, y);
right = mazesol.getBlock(x + 1, y);
```

and do :

```
if (left == 'path')
   //do whatever for left
else if (left == 'path)
   //do whatever for right
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

From your function definition I think you need to do:

```
# Check left
if mazesol.getBlock(board, x+1,y) == 'path':
# do the same for (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)
```

You will want to be careful with edge cases though, if your getBlock method doesn't check that you are in the bounds of the board you'll have to check for each case.

ie.

```
if x > 0 and mazesol.getBlock(board, x-1,y) == 'path':
```